# Is GitLab CI/CD with Unity possible for multiple developers (Unity Accounts)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gitlab, gitlab-ci

we have a small software project in Unity and we use GitLab for version control and continuous integration.

I have set up the basic `gitlab-ci.yml` file with a build for `StandaloneWindows64` as it is described in https://gitlab.com/gableroux/unity3d-gitlab-ci-example. I am using the provided shared runners from GitLab for simplicity. In order to use Unity with GitLab CI, I have to authenticate my Unity account. Therefore I have saved my Unity login credentials, as described in the steps in this [tutorial][1], in the GitLab CI/CD variables.

The thing I am not understanding yet is, doesn't every developer has to use his own Unity credentials for this? And are my credentials "safe" in those variables?

Comment: I would recommend to create a dedicated CI account for this purpose ;)